# Can we use Angular SSR and PreRendering hybrid in one app code

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, prerender

I am using Angular 5. I have added Universal in my project, reference : https://angular.io/guide/universal.

I have 5 components from which 2 components : **Component1** and **Component2** are static and does not have any typescript code, and other 3 components are dynamic and it uses typescript code.

I have also added prerender code in my app. reference : https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/

My Question is, can i use prerender for some page and ssr for some pages, as i have to improve initial load time for Component 1 and Component 2 which are static pages. even if i use the prerender ts file to create static html, when i access it from app it looks like it has loaded normal ssr route. So, Can i do prerender and ssr in my app and if i can use then how can i do it or how to check if it has worked for prerender app.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67093451/11790081) a gave to a similar question.